# Adding a node to the beginning of a double-linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to create a function that adds a node to the beginning of a double-linked list in C++, and I'm getting this error in Xcode. I know it must be because I lost the address of one of my temp nodes, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
template<typename Item>
void DLList<Item>::push_front(const Item &item) {

    /*  Adds item to a new Node at the front of the list. Updates head,
     tail, and size accordingly. Must appropriately handle cases in which the list is empty  */
        Node*p = new Node;
        p -> item = item;
        Node*oldHead = head;
        p -> next = oldHead;
        oldHead -> prev = p; /*error message: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)*/
        head = p;
        size ++;
}
```

Comment: You're not handling the case where `head` is null.

Comment: @DavidG wouldn’t it still be the same steps if head is null ?

Answer (score 1):

The error will happen when `oldHead` is `nullptr`, and then `oldHead->prev` is an invalid access. This happens when the list is empty (`head` is `nullptr`).

It is easy to fix: just make sure you only execute that statement when the list is not empty. NB: you don't actually need `oldHead`. Just keep working with `head`.

And as the comment in your code seems to suggest your list has a `tail` member, you should set it when the first node is added to the list:

```
    Node* p = new Node;
    p -> item = item;
    p -> next = head;
    if (head != nullptr) {
        head -> prev = p;
    } else {
        tail = p;
    }
    head = p;
    size ++;
```

Comment: Don't forget to update `tail` when the initial `head` is nullptr: `if (head) { head->prev = p; } else { tail = p; }`, which can alternatively be written as: `Node **n = (head) ? &(head->prev) : &tail; *n = p;` Double-pointers are very useful when dealing with linked lists to avoid `if` branches

Comment: I hadn't read the code comment ;-)  Added that now. Thanks @RemyLebeau.